# Nested dependency in aar file does not access in application

Tags: android, sdk, aar

I have created a module in which I used a dependency **api ('io.socket:socket.io-client:1.0.0')**. and that module is imported in a sample application. At that time I am not getting any problem to access socket.io class, means it works fine.

But When I created release aar file for that module. And Import aar file in the sample application but socket.io class is not accessed in application.

Please anyone, help me to resolve this type of issue.

Comment: You got any solutions. Facing issue in debug mode - I need to include the socket.io dependency again in the app module to work properly

Comment: Shashank @Mohamed Did either of you manage to figure this out? I am now also facing this issue. If I import the module directly as code it works but the release aar cannot find classes when I try and connect to the socket server.